# Finite group with nonempty intersection of left and right cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H\subseteq G$ of index $n$. Suppose that $xH\cap Hy\neq\emptyset$ for all $x,y\in G$. Prove that $|G|\ge n^2-n$.

I'm thinking we want to consider the action of $G$ on $G/H\times G/H$ acting on the left and right respectively. It suffices to show that the kernel of that map has order $n-1$ since the kernel will be contained in $H$, so $|G|=|H|n\le (n-1)n$ and we're done. However, I'm not too sure how to go about finding the order of the kernel.

The only idea I had was to let $x_1\in g_1H\cap Hg_1$, then define $x_i$ recursively so $x_i\in x_{i-1}H\cap Hg_i$ ($g_i$ coset representatives).

Any hints?

By the way, this is not for a homework problem, I'm studying for qualifying exams.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the group is $|G| = |H|\cdot |G/H|=n|H|$. So you just need to show that $H$ has at least $n-1$ elements (if I am not mistaken, you actually get $|H|\geq n$). You are told that $H=1\cdot H$ intersects every right coset non-trivially. What do you know about right cosets?

Comment: they partition the group! so each element of $1\cdot H\cap Hg_i$ is unique for each $g_i$ coset representative?